# How to setup event registration for multiple people with some additional people not paying

Tags: civievent

On WordPress, looking for suggestions on how to setup registration in this scenario:

Event Prices: Individual $50, Couple $80, Family $100

If the registrant chooses a couple one additional person does not need to pay. If they choose family, they can somehow indicate who are family members and opt out of paying for them.

This can get messy, what if someone wants to register 3 individuals, 2 couples and 1 family?

Added note in response to comment: Would like to capture additional participants information.

Comment: Are you still looking to record the names and information of the other people (besides who is filling out the form)?

Comment: Yes - otherwise a priceset with choosing a number for each type of price would suffice.